# convert json data to text/xml format using logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-integration-account

The sample json data i had in my source file

> {   "name": "pari ",   "age": 30,   "email": "pari@example.com",
> "address": {
> "street": "123 Main St",
> "city": "xyz",
> "state": "CA",
> "zip": "12345"   },   "phoneNumbers": [
> {
> "type": "home",
> "number": "112-234-1234"
> },
> {
> "type": "work",
> "number": "222-332-5678"
> }   ] }

Now i am trying to convert this into either text/xml format by using compose action. Then after data formation i want to migrate it to sql.

I have tried http request trigger and blob trigger and then blob and compose actions but i am facing issues.
As i am new to this please some one help me to create azure logic app workflow in my case .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use the `xml()` expression.

[image: Flow]

The second step has this expression ...

```
xml(json(concat('{ "root": ', variables('JSON'), '}')))
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you.  I will give it a try but i am asking about converting and then moving it to sql. You answered half of my question thanks for that.

Comment: First things first, the SQL side should be another question IMO.

Comment: Thank you . It would be great if you can provide that